# ObjectDisposedException when MultipartFormDataContent uploads too large

Tags: xamarin.forms, http-post, image-uploading, multipartform-data, idisposable

I am uploading an image from stream using the following:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
{
    formData.Add(new StreamContent(stream), "ProfileImage", fileName);
    var response = await client.PostAsync(Connection.MakeURL("Account/profilePic"), formData);
    return response;
}
```

It works fine for smaller images. But when the image is larger, at the `PostAsync` line I get the error:

> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
>   Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream'.

I have verified the disposable objects `client` and `formData` variables are not disposed at that line (disposed is false).